# unable to reverse a linked list - c language

Tags: c, linked-list, reverse

i have a simple linked list with a string, int, and next pointer in each node.

all the other linked list functions works (pop, push, delete node, etc.), but the reverse function just duplicate my node.

here is my code:

```
    personNode* reverseList(personNode* head)
    {
        personNode* curr = head;
        personNode* previous = NULL;
        personNode* next = NULL;

        while (curr != NULL)
        {
            next = curr->next;
            curr->next = previous;
            previous = curr;
            curr = next;
        }

        head = previous;
        printf("Line reversed!");

        return head;
    }
```

the results are:

Before "reversing":
[image: before]

and after:
[image: after]

(Here is The whole code:)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STR_LEN 21

typedef struct personNode
{
    char name[STR_LEN];
    int age;
    char friends[3][STR_LEN];
    struct personNode* next;

}personNode;

int recursiveLength(personNode* head, int counter);
void createPerson(char name[], int age, char friends[3][STR_LEN], personNode* head);
void link(personNode* head, personNode* toLink);
char* iHaveFriends(personNode* guest, personNode* head);
int addBehindFriend(char* friendName, personNode* guest, personNode* head);
void removePersonByName(char name[], personNode* head);
void addToListTop(personNode* VIP, personNode* head);
void search(personNode* head, char name[]);
personNode* reverseList(personNode* head);
void freeList(personNode* head);

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int choice = 0;
    char name[STR_LEN] = { 0 };
    int age = 0;
    char friends[3][STR_LEN];

    personNode* head = (personNode*)malloc(sizeof(personNode));
    head->next = NULL;

    while (choice != 7)
    {
        printf("\n\nWelcome to MagshiParty Line Management Software!\nPlease enter your choice from the following options :\n1 - Print line\n2 - Add person to line\n3 - Remove person from line\n4 - VIP guest\n5 - Search in line\n6 - Reverse line\n7 - Exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                printf("%d people in line: \n", recursiveLength(head, 0));
                recursivePrint(head);
                break;
            }

            case 2:
            {
                printf("Welcome guest!");
                printf("\nEnter name: ");
                getchar();
                scanf("%[^\t\n]s", name);
                getchar();

                printf("\nEnter age: ");
                scanf("%d", &age);

                printf("Enter names of 3 friends: ");

                for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    printf("\nFriend %d: ", i + 1);
                    getchar();
                    scanf("%[^\t\n]s", friends[i]);
                    getchar();
                }

                createPerson(name, age, friends, head);
                break;
            }

            case 3:
            {
                printf("Enter name to remove: ");
                getchar();
                scanf("%[^\t\n]s", name);
                getchar();

                removePersonByName(name, head);

                break;
            }

            case 4:
            {
                printf("VIP GUEST!\n");
                printf("Enter name: ");
                getchar();
                scanf("%[^\t\n]s", name);
                getchar();

                printf("Enter age: ");
                scanf("%d", &age);

                personNode* newNode = (personNode*)malloc(sizeof(personNode));

                newNode->age = age;
                strcpy(newNode->name, name);
                newNode->next = NULL;

                addToListTop(newNode, head);

                break;
            }

            case 5:
            {

                printf("Enter name to search: ");
                getchar();
                scanf("%[^t\n]s", name);
                getchar();

                search(head, name);

                break;
            }

            case 6:
            {
                head = reverseList(head);
                break;
            }

            case 7:
            {
                freeList(head);
                printf("Goodbye!");
                break;
            }

            default:
            {
                freeList(head);
                printf("Goodbye!");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

int recursiveLength(personNode* head, int counter)
{
    personNode* curr = head;
    if (head->next == NULL)
    {
        return counter;
    }
    else
    {
        if (curr->next != NULL)
        {
            counter++;
            recursiveLength(curr->next, counter);
        }
        else
        {
            return counter;
        }
    }
}

int recursivePrint(personNode* head)
{
    personNode* curr = head;
    if (head->next == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if (curr->next != NULL)
        {
            printf("Name: %s, Age: %d \n", curr->name, curr->age);
            recursivePrint(curr->next);
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

void createPerson(char name[], int age, char friends[3][STR_LEN], personNode* head)
{
    int i = 0;
    personNode* newNode = (personNode*)malloc(sizeof(personNode));

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        strcpy((newNode->friends[i]), friends[i]);
        //printf("inserted = %s , bimkom - %s\n", (newNode->friends[i]), friends[i]);
    }

    newNode->age = age;
    strcpy(newNode->name, name);
    newNode->next = NULL;

    link(head, newNode);
}

void link(personNode* head, personNode* toLink)
{
    personNode* curr = head;
    int i = 0;

    if (head->next == NULL) // first node - list empty
    {
        //printf("First!");
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            strcpy((head->friends[i]), (toLink->friends[i]));
            //printf("inserted = %s , bimkom - %s\n", (head->friends[i]), toLink->friends[i]);
        }
        //curr->next = malloc(sizeof(personNode));
        curr->age = toLink->age;
        strcpy(curr->name, toLink->name);
        head->next = toLink;
        //curr->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        char foundFriend[STR_LEN] = { 0 };
        strcpy(foundFriend, iHaveFriends(toLink, head));
        //printf("returned from iHaveFriends: %s", foundFriend);

        if (!addBehindFriend(foundFriend, toLink, head))
        {
            //printf("addBehindFriend Failed!");
            while (curr->next != NULL)
            {
                curr = curr->next;
            }
            //curr->next = malloc(sizeof(personNode));
            for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                *(head->friends[i]) = toLink->friends[i];
            }
            curr->age = toLink->age;
            strcpy(curr->name, toLink->name);
            curr->next = toLink;
        }
    }
}

char* iHaveFriends(personNode* guest, personNode* head)
{
    personNode* curr = head;
    int i = 0;
    char foundFriend[STR_LEN] = { 0 };

    while (curr->next != NULL)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(curr->name, guest->friends[i]) == 0)
            {
                //printf("\nMATCH: %s, %s, %s\n", foundFriend, guest->friends[i], curr->name);
                strcpy(foundFriend, guest->friends[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                //printf("\nProblem in friend Check!, compared: %s, %s\n", curr->name, guest->friends[i]);
            }
        }
        //printf("\nName: %s", curr->name);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    //printf("\nReturning: %s", foundFriend);
    return foundFriend;
}

int addBehindFriend(char* friendName, personNode* guest, personNode* head)
{
    //printf("\nrecived: %s, %s\n", friendName, guest->name);
    personNode* curr = head;
    personNode* temp = 0;
    char foundFriend[STR_LEN] = { 0 };
    int flag = 0;
    while (curr->next != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(friendName, curr->next->name) == 0)
        {
            flag = 1;
            temp = curr->next;
            curr->next = guest; 
            guest->next = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            //printf("%s, %s\n", friendName, curr->next->name);
        }
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    return flag;
}

void removePersonByName(char name[], personNode* head)
{
    personNode* curr = head;
    int flag = 0;

    while (curr->next != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(curr->next->name, name) == 0 && curr->next->next != NULL)
        {
            flag = 1;
            curr->next = curr->next->next;
            break;
        }
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    if (flag)
    {
        printf("%s removed from line", name);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s not in line", name);
    }
}

void addToListTop(personNode* VIP, personNode* head)
{
    personNode* tmp = (personNode*)(malloc(sizeof(personNode)));

    tmp->age = head->age;
    strcpy(tmp->name, head->name);
    tmp->next = head->next;

    head->age = VIP->age;
    strcpy(head->name, VIP->name);
    head->next = tmp;

    //VIP->next = tmp;
}

void search(personNode* head, char name[])
{
    personNode* curr = head;
    int flag = 0;

    while (curr->next != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(curr->name, name) == 0)
        {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    if (flag)
    {
        printf("%s found in line", name);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s not in line", name);
    }

}

personNode* reverseList(personNode* head)
{
    personNode* curr = head;
    personNode* previous = NULL;
    personNode* next = NULL;

    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        next = curr->next;
        curr->next = previous;
        previous = curr;
        curr = next;
    }

    head = previous;
    printf("Line reversed!");

    return head;
}
```

Comment: I'm just trying to understand why so many people are more inclined to take a screenshot, crop it, upload it, insert it in the post rather than select->ctrl+c->ctrl+v

Comment: Your reversal logic seems correct. I daresay the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: You forgot `#include <stdlib.h>` and `#include <string.h>`.

Comment: You have to post text as text, not images. And we are not a debugging service for a wall of code.

Comment: Not sure this is related to your problem, but this line is fishy: `*(head->friends[i]) = toLink->friends[i];`.

Comment: Seems to be working fine. Sure that the problem is not somewhere else? check this minimal example http://ideone.com/bDPjG0

Comment: `recursivePrint` is wrong. or `head` is not treated as a dummy in `reverseList`.

Comment: Not related, but using recursion here is pointless.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY , recursivePrint is working well, whats wrong?

Comment: @yossefdouieb it looks as if `recursivePrint` it is working fine, but it isn't.

Comment: @yossefdouieb You seem to treat the `head` as a dummy. But in `reverseList` it is not so. It is necessary to unify either. BTW There are other fatal errors.

Comment: in `recursivePrint` When invoked recursively, the last node is not output.

Comment: @yossefdouieb There are many other issues. The whole program is overly complicated. The origin of all problems is the fact that your head should be NULL when there are no persons in the list. Having a non NULL head if there a no persons in the list is a major design error.

Answer (score 1):

Your reverse function logic seems fine. There's a problem in your recursiveprint function, so here you go, try this simple one:

```
void print(struct personNode *head)
{
    struct personNode *temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL)

    {
        printf("%s  ", temp->name);    
        temp = temp->next;  
    }
}
```

Comment: @MukarramPasha General tip: do not duplicate existing code, just write a little comment instead ("Your function, just as is, works fine. Maybe [...]").

Answer (score 0):

The Reverse function was not working as it should on my local machine.

It was hard to debug it so I prefered to rewrite it.

> Reverse function works like this :

```
static personNode * reverse(struct personNode *head)
{
    struct personNode* localHead = NULL;
    struct personNode* temp;
    struct personNode* remainingHead;

    while (head != NULL)
    {
        remainingHead = head->next;

        temp = localHead;
        localHead = head;
        localHead->next = temp;

        head = remainingHead;
    }
    return localHead;
}
```

> Regarding youre recursive print function

I am checking the head for null , not the next pointer.

```
int recursivePrint(personNode* head)
{
    personNode* curr = head;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if (curr != NULL)
        {
            printf("Name: %s, Age: %d \n", curr->name, curr->age);
            recursivePrint(curr->next);
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```